# Маска для инпута. Баг при просмотре с телефона

Tags: html, jquery, css, input

http://webpassion9.xyz/vector
Есть поле "Время", у него задана маска --:--, при вводе с мобильного она остается. Кто знает в чем проблема и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновите плагин inputmask до новой версии, там проблем нет
http://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/

https://jsfiddle.net/qdmacp32/3/

```
$(".input-time input").inputmask('99:99');
```